# function with two parameters

Tags: functions

We have function $f(x)=x^{2014}-ax^2-bx$ determine how many roots have this function.

We have for sure one root $x=0$ becouse we can rewrite  $f(x)=x(x^{2013}-ax-b)$ but how I can determine the number of roots in bracket?

Comment: I guess, $x\in\Bbb R$. As $2013$ is odd, the polynomial $x^{2013}-ax-b$ surely has at least one real root.

Comment: Since the 3rd derivate has only the root 0, there are at most 4 roots.

Comment: The sturm chain should be easy to calculate here.

Comment: Do you mean distinct roots?

Comment: For a = 7 , b = 4 , we have 4 roots.